# Lambda for async_read_until does not initialize length parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, lambda, boost-asio

I am trying to use a c++11 lambda with boost::asio::async_read_until as follows:

```
void TCPSession::readData()
{
  auto self(shared_from_this());
  boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, buffer_, "\r\n",
  [this, self](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t length)
  {
    log()->debug("received %lu bytes && ec: %d", length, ec); //use boost::log for compile time checking
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << &buffer_;
    log()->debug("Received data: %s",ss.str());
    if (!ec){
      log()->debug("We never get here!");
      [... process data ...]
      readData();
    }
  }
 );
}
```

What I observe is that that length=0. The ec is set appropriately to the boost EOF code.

I also see the data when I convert the member (i.e. buffer_) to a string.

Any suggestions on getting the length initialized would be helpful.

An example output:

```
2014-10-09 14:47:56.968142 [tcp-session] debug: received 0 bytes && ec: asio.misc:2
2014-10-09 14:47:56.974593 [tcp-session] debug: Received data: test7.2.3.5 0.18722307655 2014-10-09 14:47:55.343591
test7.2.3.5 -0.0691607464759 2014-10-09 14:47:55.343837
test7.2.3.5 0.151471040421 2014-10-09 14:47:55.344017
test7.2.3.5 0.172789025585 2014-10-09 14:47:55.344211
test7.2.3.5 0.0409326066787 2014-10-09 14:47:55.344406
```

Comment: /How/ do you observe what you say. It could be the debugger confusing you/itself

Comment: What do you mean by "not filled"? What output do you see from your `printf` statements? Also, you don't appear to be printing `ec` at all. Can you include that as well in your output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
printf("received %lu bytes", length);

// ...
printf("Received data: %s", ss.str().c_str());
```

Or better yet,

```
std::cout << "received " << length << " bytes\n";
// ...
std::cout << "Received data: " << ss.str();
```

`%d` is not the right format for size_t. (This is why C++ was invented. Some decades ago)

***Note:*** Your compiler would have told you most of this if you enabled warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)

Now, the **[docs say](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until/overload2.html)** that

```
 // The number of bytes in the streambuf's get
 // area up to and including the delimiter.
 // 0 if an error occurred.
```

So, since the ec is EOF, this explains that `length` is also 0.

The below sample prints: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9f13235213cef00)**

```
received 0 bytes, ec: End of file
Received data: hello world
byebye
```

(Assuming that the responding server sends "hello world\n");

#### Full Sample:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>   
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

struct TCPSession : boost::enable_shared_from_this<TCPSession>
{
    void readData();

    TCPSession(boost::asio::io_service& svc) : socket_(svc) {
        using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
        socket_.connect(tcp::endpoint { {}, 6767 });
    }
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
    boost::asio::streambuf buffer_;
};

void TCPSession::readData()
{
  auto self(shared_from_this());
  boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, buffer_, "\r\n",
  [this, self](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t length)
  {
    std::cout << "received " << length << " bytes, ec: " << ec.message() << "\n";

    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << &buffer_;
    std::cout << "Received data: " << ss.str();

    if (!ec){
      std::cout << "We never get here!";
      //[... process data ...]
      readData();
    }

    std::cout << "byebye\n";
  }
 );
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service svc;
    auto sess = boost::make_shared<TCPSession>(svc);

    sess->readData();
    svc.run();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I dont believe this is the issue. I am actually using boost::log. I just replaced it with a printf for clarity. And doesnt size_t auto-typecast to a %d ?

Comment: I don't really care what you believe. Test it. I just added a much more aggravating error with missing `c_str()`. Please: compile with warnings enabled and use C++ if you can :)

Comment: What is that? Maybe you can edit it into the question instead? Note: since you used the raw temporary `ss.str()` as an argument to `printf("%s", ...)`, your program exhibited [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which could explain why `if (!ec)` was never taken.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the question. Thanks for the suggestions. The stringstream does seem to print correctly. Note though, that this is from a member variable of the class. Ok, so I modified the print statement to be as follows: 'log()->debug("received %lu bytes && ec: %d", length, ec);' & observed that ec was a boost EOF. This is great, but why is length still not filled in?

Comment: @bge0 See my updated answer. [I hope you **did** also fix the logging of the `ss.str()` into `ss.str().c_str()`. Don't forget.] Oh, and here is the self-contained reproducer **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9f13235213cef00)**

Comment: Oh perfect! I also modified \r\n to be \n & it parses properly. Since I was sending messages like '<test>\n' this never met the clause for filling in the length parameter. Enjoy credit!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62787/discussion-between-sehe-and-bge0).